# Get value of another form in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two forms on the page. One of them, say `MainForm`, is using `@using (Html.BeginForm...` to call an action upon submit, and the other, `RadioForm`,  just consists of a bunch of radios with no submit button (it's used to trigger the display of `MainForm`). If an error occurs during server-side validation, I return the View from the Controller. This though causes the radio to be deselected.

What I'm thinking is to grab the selected value of `RadioForm` so that I can set it again after the return. How would I do this? Is there a better way of persisting the state of the `RadioForm`?

Comment: Do they really have to be separate forms?

Comment: @AntP They would be preferably so, but even though it's not a must, I would like to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser won't post any form values outside of the form that's submitted, so there's no way to do this server-side. One solution would be to maintain a hidden field and update this with jQuery within the main form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RadioValue, new { @class = "radio-tracker" })
```

Give each of your radio buttons a class of, say, "radio-hidden" and use the following:

```
$('.radio-hidden').click(function() {
    $('.radio-tracker').val($(this).val());
});
```

You can then create a property on your *main* form's model called `RadioValue` and it will be bound to the selected radio button's value on post.

Then, when you return your view again, you can use this value to pre-populate the radio buttons.

Alternatively, you could look at using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the radios on a different form you need to have them on the one that submits. This way you can pass those values back to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Ajax.BeginForm` method instead of `Html.BeginForm` which allows you to specify the update target. This will allow you to update the submitted form only and not affect the radio form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)